# MomentJS keeps adding 10 days and 1 month to my date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a date that keeps getting converted to the wrong date.

This is my code:

```
      console.log("BEFORE", date);
      const formattedDate = moment(date).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      console.log("AFTER", formattedDate);
```

This prints:

```
BEFORE "2019-07-19T00:00:00.000Z"
AFTER 2019-08-29
```

Why does it keep adding 10 days and 1 month to my date?? This is happening in my React Native app. However, when I go to momentjs.com and open up the console, it prints the right thing!

momentjs.com

```
moment("2019-07-19T00:00:00.000Z").format("YYYY-MM-DD")
"2019-07-18"
```

Comment: I don't have this issue here, maybe a global config?

Comment: I haven't configured anything. I feel like something in the React Native ecosystem is messing it up ?

Comment: I figured out a solution but it's odd. See below

Comment: Was about to post this, https://jsfiddle.net/1v7c69nd/, but seems like you already figured that out. FWIW, that might actually be printing today's date, depending on your time zone.

Comment: Ohhhh that could be why it's off by 1 day. But I want to just return `2019-07-19` regardless of timezone. Would there be a way to do that?

Comment: The fiddle I created does properly format your universal date/time to date. I don't work with React, so I have no idea _where_ it would be coming from, but have you tried using a variable name other than "date"? That would tell you if somehow you're calling some React date function (or something in your app is setting that as a global variable).

Comment: This seems to have fixed it! `const formattedDate = moment.utc(new Date(date)).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround. I create a new Date with `new Date(date)` and then wrap that with `moment.utc` instead of just `moment`

```
      console.log("BEFORE", date);
      const formattedDate = moment.utc(new Date(date)).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
      console.log("AFTER", formattedDate);
```

This prints: (which is what I want)

```
BEFORE 2019-07-19T00:00:00.000Z
AFTER 2019-07-19
```

Comment: Can you show us how do you create date.  It also can be linked to the timezone

Comment: Unfortunately it's a date that's being created from another library so I'm not the one making it. Thanks for the help though

Comment: Which library is that?, there is definitely something wrong in the Date object. As the issue doesn't come from moment because it works fine by creating a date string

Comment: Actually I realized it's a day off now. https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars. The "renderEmptyDate" section

Comment: another work around without using momentjs `console.log("DATE", date.split("T")[0]);` if date is a string

Comment: Fixed it with moment.utc